# React router stopped working after adding "createBrowserHistory" with saga

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, redux-saga

I'm learning React.js and I struggled with the following problem:

My react app stopped working after adding "createBrowserHistory" with Saga.

Essentially, I want to redirect users to the Cart Page (/cart) when I click on "Add to Cart" button.

Example:

That is the home page:

[image]

When I click on "Add to Cart" button, it navigates to the "/cart" route. However, it doesn't show anything and, there is no error in the console.

[image]

I have made the following changes in my code:

Added history package:

[image]

Created history file:

[image]

Changed App.js file:

[image]

Changed saga file. I expect to navigate to the "/cart" route after doing some jobs...

[image]

**The problem is here!** I want to fix the problem in my saga file only.

I've created a Pull Request here, to reproduce the error. Feel free to have a look at this.

https://github.com/willianfalbo/online-shoes-app/pull/1

**I'm willing to bounty someone who creates a PR for me. I will also accept your answer here!**

Comment: Why do you need `createBrowserHistory` history in the first place? When your `redux-saga` does the `api` call, and after the success, wouldn't it be better to return the control to your React components to process later. Meaning, you could easily change the route in your `React component` instead in `sagas` which would negate the use of `createBrowserHistory` in the first place..

Comment: Try changing to `yield call(history.push, '/cart');`

Comment: @AlekseyL., I've tried this way but didn't work.

Comment: @PrãtéékThápá, do you have any example?

Comment: You could test with `MemoryHistory` and see if it's still broken in that context. Not a solution, but might elucidate something

Comment: Thank's @Slbox! Do you have any link example?

Comment: @Willian instead of importing `createBrowserHistory`, import `createMemoryHistory`. We're still on `history@4.x`, but I think it should still work in `5.x`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like react-router 5x version are only compatible with history.4x.

Downgrading the history version to 4.2.0 works.

Comment: @Willian I've send the PR.

Comment: Fantastic bro! Thank you for creating a PR for me! Great job. I'm not able to bounty you now, because I have to wait 24 hours to do so. Btw, as I accepted your answer, StackOverflow you bounty you automatically. Cheers

Comment: I'm just curious. Are you building it for production or just a practice app?

Comment: It is just for practising as I started to learn React last month. Do you have any suggestion? Any help you welcome =)

Comment: I feel like you're overdoing stuff. I've written a few production apps in React.
I don't think you need `sagas` to begin with. `Redux thunk` would do. Also, your app can make do with using the Context API rather than redux also.

In short, your app could make do with using the `Context API`. No need for redux, redux-sagas, and immer.

Comment: That was a great tip buddy! I was pretty much disappointed about using Redux/Saga. In my opinion, it is too much complex and complicated. Definitely, I'm gonna start studying Context API. Do you recommend any online course?

Comment: You could have a look at [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=35lXWvCuM8o).It's not complicated, you could get away with just reading the docs.

Comment: Thanks for this - just saved my life :)